Interesting behavior of an $H$ field mode in ring resonator
I have built the following resonator. 
It has magnetic field normal to the substrate plane. 
but for some reason at the exact resonance i get the magnetic field bad(photo 2) 
Hoever at the frequency near the resonance I got a very very good responce. 
What could cause sucha thing? 
How can I make the $H$-field be that good at the resonance point? 
When I tried to move the resonance by changing capacitor value , I still got the same phenomena where the good $H$-field behavior is not at the resonance but very close to it. 
I Also made a video describing the situation live and attached the CST model in the links. 
Thanks. \
Photo 1: 






Hi rocko445. Welcome to Phys.SE. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. this meta post.

Ok I will remove them.please open the question
